# How to make dropdown menu full width and push content with only HTML+CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I am trying to create pure and simple HTML+CSS drop down menu which will open in a full width mode underneath each item and will also push content. This image and jsfiddle better explains what I am trying to achieve:

jsfiddle.net/66qez5tn

[image]

How do I do this ?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/66qez5tn](http://jsfiddle.net/66qez5tn) Here is my code. Sorry for late reply!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have added your image inline.  And I have removed the tanks and the plea, they are not required.

Comment: @RohitGupta You are great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This code can do the drop down menu with HTML and CSS:

```
 <style>
/* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to make drop down menu full width and push content down like this image.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/3k2bL.png